# MongoDB "connect ETIMEDOUT"

Tags: mongodb, etimedout

I suddenly cannot connect to my database! This issue occurred out of nowhere just the other day and I have not been able to figure out why.

I have pm2 processes running that are using the database and are working correctly. However, if I restart one of the process's, it will stop working with the database. **This and the fact that I am unable to connect through atlas/compass are my issues.**

I did recently start a [mastodon](https://docs.joinmastodon.org/admin/install/) on my VPS which could be (I think it is) the reason why my mongodb has encountered issues. I messed with a lot of different settings including some port stuff; I think this is where my issue may lie.

A friend of mine believes this is a port issue so he had me enable the default mongo port (27017) with ufw using the commands below:

```
sudo ufw allow 27017
```

```
sudo ufw allow 27017/tcp
```

After some in depth research, I have not yet been able to find an answer to this issue; I am praying someone here may be of help.

My `mongo.conf` file has not changed at all and can the start of it can be seen below:

```
# mongodb.conf

# Where to store the data.
dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb

#where to log
logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log

logappend=true

bind_ip = 127.0.0.1,23.29.118.167
port = 27017

# Enable journaling, http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Journaling
journal=true

# Enables periodic logging of CPU utilization and I/O wait
#cpu = true

# Turn on/off security.  Off is currently the default
#noauth = true
auth = true
```

Comment: `mastodon` install instructions seems to make several `iptables` rules.  Can you find your connection attempts as `"iptables denied: "` entries in the log file?

Comment: Is this your real config file? Looks like you are using a very old version of MongoDB.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit it is just the start of my config, not the entire file.

Comment: @rickhg12hs there is nothing regarding "iptables" in the log file located at `/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log`

Comment: `iptables` logs would most likely be in the system log, perhaps `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/messages`.

Comment: My mistake, I thought you meant the `mongodb` logs. I cannot find the `iptables` logs anywhere. The only directories in `/var/log` are the following: `apache2, apt, caddy, dist-upgrade, installer, journal, landscape, letsencrypt, mongodb, nginx, pgadmin, postgresql, private, redis, sysstat, unattended-upgrades`

Comment: Does `journalctl -g iptables` show anything?

Comment: Yes actually, you can see below:
`Dec 14 01:18:32 server-liege-dev kernel: iptables denied: IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=REDACTED SRC=REDACTED DST=REDACTED LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=242 ID=54321 PROTO=TCP S>
Dec 14 01:18:44 server-liege-dev kernel: iptables denied: IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=REDACTED SRC=REDACTED DST=REDACTED LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=238 ID=54321 PROTO=TCP S>`
I redacted some of the numbers because I do not know what they mean and I don't want to leak any of my information.

Comment: This is looking like a `iptables` configuration/rules issue. I doubt anything is wrong with MongoDB. Time to debug the firewall configuration.

Comment: Not exactly sure how to do that; is there an `iptables` command I can use to simply allow `27017` or mongo itself to allow remote access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uninstalled and reinstalled `iptables` and then did `iptables -F` which "Delete[s] all rules in  chain or all chains"

This fixed my issue, but I think I might have to reconfigure some of my `iptables` stuff.